# Mirror a dataset with future days for forecasting

Tags: r, dataframe, date, forecast

Guess this is pretty basic but I'm struggling to find a way and find a answer online either. I'm trying to create a dataframe with future dates but those dates should be duplicated per combinations of other 2 variables

so I should have

Dates | Channel  | Product

Channel can take 4 values and product 7 values and I need to create dates for future 45 days after my last day in current df. Therefore I have 28 combinations per day and my new df should be 1260 rows (45 * 7 *4)
as the sample below
[image]
I know about this function

```
Dates =seq(max(train$Date), by="day", length.out=45)
```

However this will create a vector not duplicating dates for each combination. Anyway I can adapt this?

Comment: Something like `expand.grid(Channel = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Product = 1:7, Date = seq(max(train$Date), by="day", length.out=45))`

Comment: Also, 45 * 7 * 4 = 1260, not 1170.

Comment: yeah my bad not sure where that came out. it works perfectly! thanks!